# R - (why) does fitting a binomial glm to a 3-level factor work?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, lme4-nlme

I am trying to determine which of several independent variables {A,B,C} best predicts a subject's response R, which can be one of 3 choices, {high, medium, low}.

As the dependent variable is multinomial i.e. not binomial, a binomial logistic regression is not suitable. However, using the lme4 package to fit a glm with `family = 'binomial'` to the data runs without error or warning, and correctly identifies that independent variable B is the best predictor.

Is this a lucky coincidence, or is the call to `glm()` automatically fitting multiple binomial regressions to the data (one for each binary combination), or is it something else entirely? Any comments are welcome.

Comment: Do you have reproducible code? For both glmer() and glm(), I get the error "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : y values must be 0 <= y <= 1."

Comment: @Donnie all of the variables are factors, including the dependent variable, which can take on one of three levels.

Comment: I've updated the question to better reflect this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what's happening:

> For binomial and quasibinomial families the response can also be specified as a factor (when the first level denotes failure and all others success) or as a two-column matrix with the columns giving the numbers of successes and failures.

Taken from the `glm.fit` [docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/glm.html).